# Google APIs/OAuth2 for .NET: dll integration/version issue

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

Ran the following in NuGet:

```
PM > Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 -Pre
PM > Install-Package Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc -Pre
```

Per instructions at following locations

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/1.7.0.72-beta

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc

After adding these to the project and just a leaving a reference to Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data from a previous version that did not make use of the newly added references I get the following when attempting to build (I have tried cleaning first)

> The type 'Google.Apis.Requests.IDirectResponseSchema' is defined in an assembly 
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Google.Apis, 
>   Version=1.7.0.24060, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Additional Facts

- Google.Apis is definitely included.
- The version number the Google.Apis dll reference added by NuGet is 1.7.0.34454
- I checked in the registry (under .NET 4) and am running v4.5.xxxx
- While solution explorer shows the assemblies under references they do not show up in the object explorer
- When trying to reference namepaces/classes in these assemblies Intellisense is able to find them but when you build it says that it can not find the referenced namespace(s)
- I verified that all google dlls are from the 1.7.x.xxxx (different build numbers)
- We were originally referencing an older version  of Google Calendar API but that reference was definitely updated to the most recent version

Exchanging the Google Calendar namespace reference with

```
using Google.Apis.Auth;
```

results in

> The type or namespace name 'Auth' does not exist in the namespace 'Google.Apis' 
>   (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This appears to have been a an issue with that particular version  of the Google APIs, Google seems to have fixed it in the most recent version.